# How to make Hyperlink in a List Item to hidden on overflow?

Tags: html, css

The hyperlink always wraps. Is there a way to hide the overflow?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the following should do what you want.

```
a.specialLink {
    display:inline-block;
    overflow:hidden;
    white-space:nowrap;
    width: 10em;
}
```

Comment: cant use inline-block in ie 7. Nevertheless, Whitespace: nowrap seems to have done it. thanks.

Comment: inline-block in IE7 only works on inline elements, not block elements. a 'span' or 'a' (both inline elements) can be given display:inline-block whereas a div could not

Comment: inline-block should work in ie... but it doesn't work in ffx 2

Answer (score 0):

HTML:

```
<ul id="hide">
    <li><a href="/path">Link</a></li>
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
#hide li a {overflow: hidden;}
```